Browser not saving cookie when sending request to authenticate
So I have built an API using express. Now I am creating the frontend using React and Vite.
When my frontend sends a request to the api login route, the response includes the corresponding Set-Cookie header for the session ID. However, the cookie is not being saved in the browser.
Since It's in development, the frontend is being served by a different port than the backend. I understand this might be the issue, but I am not sure.
I read somewhere proxying the request could help, but I still don't see the cookie being stored.
The backend is NOT rejecting the request due to CORS issues, I have included CORS middleware in the backend and as I said, the server is responding, it's just the frontend which is not storing the cookie.
How can I solve this problem?

Solution
As indicated in the solution to this question, I had to do some modifications to the CORS middleware:
app.use(
  cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
  credentials: true,
})
);

And the axios request:
await axios.post(
  "http://localhost:3000/auth/login",
  {
    password,
  },
  {
    withCredentials: true,
  }
);

These changes being made, the browser successfully saved the session cookie.
